# Avalonia : Hiding titlebar window on Linux does not work

Tags: titlebar, avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm using avalonia (version 0.10.3 - but the same happened with 0.10.0 - on Net5.0 project) as the UI for a project and when I create for instance a splash or an about screen, the title bar must be invisible.

On windows this works just fine with these parameters in the window section :

```
CanResize="False"
ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"
ExtendClientAreaChromeHints="NoChrome"
ExtendClientAreaTitleBarHeightHint="0"
```

Unfortunately, on Linux (mint - latest version with latest updates), the title bar remains visible (also if I set ExtendClientAreaTitleBarHeightHint="-1").

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong ?

I do not have a mac, but is that also the case for mac ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X11 uses so-called "server decorations". Window frame is drawn by a window manager in a *separate process*, so it's not really possible to extend into that area.

You can still disable the frame completely and draw your own, but in general it's not really recommended since you will break advanced window interactions in basically every non-GNOME based Linux distro (GNOME doesn't care because it doesn't have any advanced window interactions).

In some future version Avalonia would use a custom-drawn frame for GNOME with a configuration option to ignore your user's preferences in favor of a fancy looking window border for other desktop environments as well, but it's not implemented yet.

Comment: OK thanks Kekekeks, Macos is a unix derivative, is the same applicable for mac then ?

Comment: I just read that macos now uses xquartz instead of x11. My question however remains. Is the behavior on quartz more like windows (without the titlebar) or linux (with the titlebar) ?

Comment: macOS doesn't use X11. It has its own display manager with its own UI toolkit. You can still install an X-server for X11-only apps, but it just proxies those to the real one.

Comment: Regarding you question: window chrome extension does work on macOS, but note that window buttons are at the left and that you probably want to fine-tune your UI layout for macOS because the title bar height is different.

Comment: Thanks Kekekeks. Except for the tiltlebar in linux, does this have impact on other UI elements on linux ?

Comment: No, it should not

Answer (score 3):

This is how this can be achieved in Avalonia 0.10.18

```xml
<Window ...
        ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"
        ExtendClientAreaChromeHints="NoChrome"
        ExtendClientAreaTitleBarHeightHint="-1"
        SystemDecorations="BorderOnly">
```

Note `SystemDecorations="BorderOnly"` attribute. If it is not set, decorations are hidden on Windows but not on Linux.

I found this solution in one of the posts in related Avalonia bug https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/5829#issuecomment-841700569

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I "solve it" by defining the window property as:

```
WindowState = WindowState.FullScreen;
```

Comparing with *Normal* or *Maximized*, with title bar in fullscreen remains hidden.

Comment: Nice SM_PT, if all screens can be fullscreen, that can be an option !